# Search text using regex that ignore html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to add highlight class around searched text. But the other html tags are in my way. Here is an example:

Starting with:

```
<div class="source">your <b><i>text</i></b> using <a href="#">regex ignoring html</a> tags</div>
```

And I search for: `text using regex`

The expected result (in this example I will use `span` for highlight):

```
<div class="source">your <b><i><span>text</span></i></b><span> using </span><a href="#"><span>regex</span> ignoring html</a> tags</div>
```

I have solution for this but it require specific regex that search for text ignoring html tags inside. **If there is an solution other then presented below I'm open for suggestion. And it doesn't have to be written in vanilla js**. Below is simplified version of my current solution that lack mentioned regex.

*example below don't work because of missing regex*

```
var source = document.querySelector('.source').innerHTML; // html from example
var text = 'text using regex'; // what we searching for
var htmlTag = new RegExp('(<\\/?([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>))+', 'g'); // find html tags
var missingRegExp = new RegExp('', 'i'); // << missing regex

// Wrap searched text with span tag
var result = source.replace(missingRegExp, function (searchedText) {
  // Wrap html tags inside searched text with span tag
  searchedText = searchedText.replace(htmlTag, function (match) {
    return '</span>' + match + '<span>';
  });

  return '<span>' + searchedText + '</span>';
});

console.log('Result: ' + result);
```

In this case removing html tags is not an option.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, try [mark.js](https://markjs.io)

Comment: Try `var source = document.querySelector('.source').textContent` instead.

Comment: @dude I will try mark.js. For as I look at examples there is nothing that looks like my issue. But maybe I need to tweak some options. Thanks dude.

Comment: @zer00ne ok textContent. But what next? I need to have tags from inside back. Look at example.

Comment: `.textContent` is text no tags. No need for regex, this is advice not an answer, hence in the comments rather in an answer.

Comment: He doesn't need only to search but search and replace in current context. @zer00ne

Comment: *"search for text ignoring html tags inside"* What I read. And desired result is the matched text being wrapped in a span for highlighting nothing more than that.

Comment: So you read only title? *I need to add highlight class around searched text.* If OP was dealing with raw text there was no need for him to ignore any HTML tags in between. Your solution simply doesn't fit this problem. @zer00ne

Comment: What solution? Did I post an answer? **Look at the desired result** Why would you need to be concerned with tags in the first place? The span are wrapping the matched text **NOTHING ELSE**

Comment: `<div class="source">your <b><i><span>text</span></i></b><span> using </span><a href="#"><span>regex</span> ignoring html</a> tags</div>`=`'your text using regex ignoring html'`

Comment: Although you didn't post an answer, you are proposing a solution in comments. Insisting that it works. Suggesting original poster to follow it. *The span are wrapping the matched text **NOTHING ELSE*** it's not entirely true. Matched text should be wrapped in `span` tags but within **current** context. `.textContent` property will only return raw text inside a tag. You can match string but you can't replace it with new values while *leaving other HTML tags **alone** in their current positions*. The important part is **replacing** not matching. @zer00ne

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a string like `text using regex`. You should care about middle spaces and replace them with appropriate RegEx to match HTML tags but at first you need to enclose each word in parentheses:

```
> '(' + "text using regex".split(' ').join(') (') + ')'
< "(text) (using) (regex)"
```

Next step is replacing spaces with RegEx: `((?:\s*(?:<\/?\w[^<>]*>)?\s*)*)` so our last modified version should be:

```
< "(text)((?:\s*(?:<\/?\w[^<>]*>)?\s*)*)(using)((?:\s*(?:<\/?\w[^<>]*>)?\s*)*)(regex)"
```

If we had 3 words to search then we end to have 5 capturing groups totally (`n` words -> `n` + `n-1` capturing groups), so you should create a replacement string based on that. Here we should have our replacement string as such:

```
<span>$1</span>$2<span>$3</span>$4<span>$5</span>
```

Now you have your compiled RegEx version and replacement string, `.replace()` method will put a successful end to them.

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK8fQ3/1)**

Comment: One improvement is needed. When you searching for single word or for multiple words (when spaces are hidden html tags) it works just fine. But if you search for multiple words and spaces are just spaces then it fails. You need to change regex to: `(((?:\s*<\/?\w[^<>]*>\s*)*)|\s)`. Thanks @revo.

Comment: Using `.replace` on `innerHTML` will destroy events and triggers regeneration of the DOM. Again, you shouldn't reinvert the wheel and instead use an existing plugin like [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) or [highlightRegex](https://github.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex).

Comment: Yes, right and you don't need an extra alternation. See my update. @irek

Comment: While working with `document` object, you shouldn't be worry about that. Nobody is reinventing wheel. When only *a few lines* are needed to finish a task completely, you shouldn't be that lazy to borrow others' works immediately instead which probably provide more functionalities than needed. @dude

Comment: I'm going to use jQuery version of mark.js anyway. @dude

Comment: But @revo show working solution for question I asked in the first place.